# LM317 PWM Output Equation_Calculation

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog

I was trying to find the output of the LM317 PWM circuit obtained from this EDN article: ([Circuit](https://www.edn.com/control-an-lm317t-with-a-pwm-signal/)).

I want Vout in terms of PWM. Below is my analysis. May I know it is correct or not.

will all the OPAMPS be able to sink the minimum load current required by the LM317. May I know the things to be taken care of while selecting the OPAMAP?

If wrong please let me know where I went wrong

[image: My calculations]

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: For the LM317 Vout = Vadj + 1.25, so yes, I_L = 1.25V/330R.

Comment: Note R1 C1 in the schematic filter the PWM, without them the output of the opamp and LM317 will be a square wave like your PWM.

Comment: Thank you all. I have added one more question. Could you please check it.

Comment: You MUST filter your PWM to DC. | Vout = Vpwm_source x PWM_duty_cycle x 2 + 1.25 V. 
 1.25V is LM317 Vout-Vref differential. Balance is PWM DC value x 2.

Comment: May I know is this ("Vpwm_source x PWM_duty_cycle" ) the DC output from the filter.

Comment: re "May I know ..." -> Yes, as long as the filtering is good enough. With indequate filtering you get ripple which the LM317 tries to track. I find that 3rd order Bessel fiter is usually good enough. This can be looked up in any filter calculator and takes a single op amp to implement.